# Returning the position of strings in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array already made, I want the user to enter two different strings such as "ITEC" for the department and "110" for the courseNumber. Then I want to search the array to see if those strings are one after another such as "ITEC 110" in the entire array. I then want it to return the two numbers at the beginning of the string that it is in.

Part of the array's contents look like this, with about 15 additional lines that look similar:

0 0 Core 101 3 University Core A: Core 101
0 1 ITEC 110 3 Introduction to Information Technology

Here is a part of the code that I have:

```
if ("find".equals(option))
{
  String department;
  String courseNumber;

  System.out.print("Please enter the Department:\n");
  department = scan.next();
  System.out.print("Please enter the Course Number:\n");            
  courseNumber = scan.next();

  int count = 0;

  Courses[] POS = new Courses[50];

  while (scan.hasNext())
  {
    POS[count] = new Courses(scan.nextLine());
    if (POS[count].equals(department + "" + courseNumber))
      System.out.println("YES");

    count++;
  }
  System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Comment: Consider using classes for tightly-coupled data (instead of array positions).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can concatenating the two strings(Department, CourseNumber)
2. Iterating over the array and looking for the string is contains the concatenating strings.
3. taking the first two words of the matching string.

Comment: @user1781453, We can't write your code, we can help you with it.